# How to catch and display the extact error message in python

Tags: python, mysql, extract-error-message

I have codes which uses python to insert data from excel into mysql.
I am trying to catch some error message and display more clear information to the end user, like:

if you are trying to insert NaN into mysql, the system show below info:
'''
1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'
'''

How can I catch this error message to display more clear info, like:

```
if ErrorCode='1054':
    print('please check at original file at see whether there is empty value at certain area"
```

I use

```
try: 
except Exception as:
    print(e)
```

to catch the error message, but this can not show the explicit info.
I might be wrong, please feel free to commet it.
Thanks.

Comment: Which package are you using to connect to MySQL?  The error code might be an attribute of the exception, but it's likely to be implementation-dependent.

Comment: I use mysql.connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is quite straight forwar see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html)

```
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
  if err.errno == 1054:
    print("please check at original file at see whether there is empty value at certain area")
  else:
    print("Another error")
```